# mp4 video doesn't play in video tag in html 5

Tags: php, html

Hi iam still struggling play mp4 format  in video tag in html 5  here is my code

```
 <?php
    ?>
    <video width="560" height="340" controls>
      <source src="http://ifliptips.com/admin/abc.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    </video>

    <?PHP
    ?>
```

here is link `http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/video.php`

can any one guide me what i wrong in this code.i try to play this link in chrome as well as IE9.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Which web browser do you use? mp4 doesn't work in firefox.

Comment: i use chrome but video could play

Comment: I have this same issue, what did you do to get it to play?

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the way you encoded your video. If you open your current video in VLC and go to Codec Information you'll see under video it says: `Codec: mp4v` but you're specifying the video codec is `avc1.42E01E` in your type attribute.

I don't know what codecs the browsers are restricted to playing, but if you convert your video 
to avc1 (you can download a converted version here: http://www.online-convert.com/result/d1bb21daf90f8b77377d4c9f81398eff -- see it's codec info in VLC has changed to `avc1`) the browsers will play it.

Wayne

Comment: And remember you'll need to encode some other formats if you want to support other browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=video)